# Flag creation based on count of consecutive ones in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

1. I have a data frame with a column with only 0's and 1's. I need to create a flag column where there are more than a certain number of consecutive ones in the first column.
2. In the example below, `x >= 4` , if there are 4 or more consecutive one's, then the flag should be 1 for all those consecutive rows.

```
   col1   Flag
0     1     0
1     0     0
2     1     1
3     1     1
4     1     1
5     1     1
6     0     0
7     1     0
8     1     0
9     0     0
10    1     1
11    1     1
12    1     1
13    1     1
14    1     1
15    0     0
```

1. One change, let's say there is a new column group, we need to group by that and find the flag,

```
    Group   col1   Flag
0     A       1     0
1     B       0     0
2     B       1     1
3     B       1     1
4     B       1     1
5     B       1     1
6     C       0     0
7     C       1     0
8     C       1     0
9     C       0     0
10    D       1     0
11    D       1     0
12    D       1     0
13    E       1     0
14    E       1     0
15    E       0     0
```

2. As you can there are consecutive ones from 10 to 14 but they belong to different groups. And elements in group can be in any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in a couple of steps:

- `rolling(4).sum()` to attain consecutive summations of your column
- Use `where` to get the 1's from `"col1"` where their summation window (from the previous step) is >= 4. Turn the rest of the values into `np.NaN`
- `bfill(limit=3)` to backwards fill the leftover 1s in your column by a maximum of 3 places.
- `fillna(0)` fill what's leftover with 0

```
df["my_flag"] = (df["col1"]
                 .where(
                     df["col1"].rolling(4).sum() >= 4  
                 )                 # Selects the 1's whose consecutive sum >= 4. All other values become NaN
                 .bfill(limit=3)   # Moving backwards from our leftover values, 
                                      # take the existing value and fill in a maximum of 3 NaNs
                 .fillna(0)        # Fill in the rest of the NaNs with 0
                 .astype(int))     # Cast to integer data type, since we were working with floats temporarily

print(df)
    col1  Flag  my_flag
0      1     0        0
1      0     0        0
2      1     1        1
3      1     1        1
4      1     1        1
5      1     1        1
6      0     0        0
7      1     0        0
8      1     0        0
9      0     0        0
10     1     1        1
11     1     1        1
12     1     1        1
13     1     1        1
14     1     1        1
15     0     0        0
```

---

Edit:

For a grouped approach, you just need to use `groupby().rolling` to create your mask for use in `where()`. Everything after that is the same. I separated the rolling step to keep it as readable as possible:

```
grouped_counts_ge_4 =  (df.groupby("Group")["col1"]
                        .rolling(4)
                        .sum()
                        .ge(4)
                        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))


df["my_flag"] = (df["col1"]
                 .where(grouped_counts_ge_4)
                 .bfill(limit=3)   # Moving backwards from our leftover values, take the existing value and fill in a maximum of 3 NaNs
                 .fillna(0)        # Fill in the rest of the NaNs with 0
                 .astype(int))     # Cast to integer data type, since we were working with floats temporarily

print(df)
   Group  col1  Flag  my_flag
0      A     1     0        0
1      B     0     0        0
2      B     1     1        1
3      B     1     1        1
4      B     1     1        1
5      B     1     1        1
6      C     0     0        0
7      C     1     0        0
8      C     1     0        0
9      C     0     0        0
10     D     1     0        0
11     D     1     0        0
12     D     1     0        0
13     E     1     0        0
14     E     1     0        0
15     E     0     0        0
```

Comment: can you please update the answer for the change above?

Comment: can you do group by and then apply the rolling function?

Comment: I've added how to use this via groupby. In the future, please don't add additional questions once a question has already been answered. Instead accept the solution you find is best, and open a new question asking about how to extend the current answer.

Answer (score 2):

No that hard try with `cumsum` create the key then do the `transform` `count`

```
(df.groupby(df.col1.ne(1).cumsum())['col1'].transform('count').ge(5) & df.col1.eq(1)).astype(int)
Out[83]: 
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    1
14    1
15    0
Name: col1, dtype: int32
```

Comment: can you please update your answer for the change above?

Comment: @ANKALUGARIRANGAHARSHAVARDHAN `(df.groupby([df.col1.ne(1).cumsum(),df['Group']])['col1'].transform('count').ge(5) & df.col1.eq(1)).astype(int)
`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['Flag'] = np.where(df['col1'].groupby((df['col1'].diff().ne(0) | df['col1'].eq(0)).cumsum()).transform('size').ge(4),1,0)
```